# Using plexiglass instead of aluminum plate for router table

Tags: safety, router-table

I'm about to re-design my router table.I used 8mm Iron as plate and cut the support holes with cnc laser, but the heat of cutting deformed the surface and made me to refine that with grinding machine.

Recently I found plexiglass, the surface of them is very smooth and I want to replace that ( with 10mm or 15mm ) with current Iron plate .the only concern is the safety and broken risk while working. would you please help me on this matter.

PS: I can't order ready aluminum plate and I have to make it on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plexiglass may not be the best choice, but there are other plastics that may work better with less deflection and a better wearing surface.  Several manufacturer's use phenolic plastics for router plate inserts and there are companies online that sell sheets in a variety of sizes and thicknesses so it should be possible to make your own.  I considered making my own a year ago (but opted for a different approach for my table using mdf board).  If I remember correctly I was considering using 3/8" thick sheet for a 12" square insert plate.    I believe that should be adequate for a router table application.

Add an answer to let us know how it works out if you choose this route.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some 3/8" lexan, which you can usually get from the Home Store.

I would recommend some solid surface(ie. Corian, etc.) if you can get your hands on a piece. It can be machined using normal woodworking tools, and is very stable, and has a smooth finish that is great for durability and sliding parts across easily.

Answer (score 2):

Plexiglass is probably too flexible for this purpose.

If you can't get a plate, remember that you *can* bolt the router directly to the underside of a table. It isn't as convenient, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Plexiglass is probably fine to use as long as it is well-supported. Note that it will be significantly softer than the aluminum, so it will be more prone to getting scratched or marred by anything metal. Therefore, you will want to use soft-jaw clamps, wooden (rather than metal) straight edges, and other more gentle fixturing.

As long as you observe those precautions, plexiglass should work fine.

One advantage of plexigass is that it is transparent, so you can, for example, put measuring tape or guidelines on the bottom surface.